# Number of query values and destination fields are not the same in vb6 Error

Tags: sql, vb6

I want to ask something,

I wrote the code like this, but when I execute that, it contain an error like this

"Number of query values and destination fields are not the same"

Before I show my code, I'll show you my structural table :

```
No : AutoNumber
NoNota : Text
NamaMotor : Text
NamaPeg : Text
Unit : Number
TotalJasa : Number
TotalPart : Number
GrandTotal : Number
```

Here's my code below :

```
 dung = "INSERT INTO TmpTransaksi VALUES (" & _
                      "" & TBox(33).Text & "," & _
                      "'" & TBox(0).Text & "'," & _
                      "'" & TBox(32).Text & "'," & _
                      "'" & TBox(30).Text & "'" & _
                      "" & TBox(25).Text & "," & _
                      "" & TBox(23).Text & "," & _
                      "" & TBox(15).Text & "," & _
                      "" & TBox(16).Text & ")"
       MsgBox dung
       cn.Execute dung
```

Can you tell me where's my fault and correct it?
Thanks before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a comma. Change

```
"'" & TBox(30).Text & "'" & _
                      ^^^
```

to

```
"'" & TBox(30).Text & "'," & _
```

**On a side note:** consider to learn and use parameterized queries instead of interpolating query strings.